# Accidentally removed python package in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I accidently removed python package in anaconda.

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:

python:   2.7.11-0              
selenium: 2.40.0-py27_0 metaperl
```

Now it says:

```
-bash: /Users/xx/anaconda/bin/conda: /Users/xx/anaconda/bin/python: bad     interpreter: No such file or directory
```

What I can do it re-install python package in anaconda? I tried

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda
```

but all conda command now seems fail

Comment: you removed the environment or the package ? `conda create` is for environment creation...

Comment: Any conda command seems fail now because there is no python directory, :(

Comment: @AlexFung I removed the package

Comment: I have no idea what do you mean by Python package... a library or a directory or a .exe. And btw great name.

Comment: @AlexFung   Below is what I have done: The following packages will be REMOVED:

    python:   2.7.11-0              
    selenium: 2.40.0-py27_0 metaperl

Comment: Reinstall conda with the installer would be the simplest way.

Comment: @AlexFung Thanks, will reinstalling conda remove all other packages I previously have installed in anaconda folder?

Comment: reinstalling conda is very likely to remove everything in the anconda folder. Be sure to back up the things.